# Exit column mode for vim

Tags: macos, vim, editor, vi

I was trying to enter column mode (`:%!column -t`)in vim to view a csv, but it delineated by something other than a comma and now my information is unreadable, and `CTRL-V` now no longer displays the above command, but instead displays `:%!column -t^M`.

How would I exit vim/fix this?

Comment: There is no column mode in Vim. More info at `:help vim-modes`.

Comment: I figured that out afterwards, but I seem to be hitting an error for any help commands. I get the message `E432: Tags file not sorted: /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/doc/tags`. I tried upgrading using homebrew but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ man column | grep "\-s"
     column [-entx] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]
     -s      Specify a set of characters to be used to delimit columns for the -t option.
             by default, or with the characters supplied using the -s option.  Useful for pretty-printing displays.
```

There is `-s` option which allows you to specify delimiter you need.

You can undo changes in vim using <kbd>u</kbd> button.